# Unable to schedule ANY reminders

Tags: scheduled-reminders

I am not able to schedule any reminders.  This happens whens pretty much everywhere.. whether I'm trying to set this up for Events, or even generally in **CiviCRM > Administrator > Communications > Schedule Reminders**

Anyone have any idea what is going on?  This is the only error I get..

FYI:  Powered by CiviCRM 5.6.0

> Error: Call to undefined method
>   CRM_Admin_Form_ScheduleReminders::setContext() in
>   CRM_Admin_Form_ScheduleReminders->buildQuickForm() (line 69 of
>   .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/ScheduleReminders.php).

Comment: Does your System Status screen show any issues?

Comment: No..  System Status shows everything is green.  I also just upgraded to 5.7.0 this morning and still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue..  I tracked it down to the fact that I'm using custom templates to modify CiviCRM.

the **civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php** file has been updated to a new version while my custom version I had in the Custom Template Directory was still using the older version.

I synced them up and everything is working fine now.